# Symfony 3.4 loop over fields in form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have simple form with 6 checkboxes with a label and a name.

I just want to display them into bootstrap templating :

```
{% for child in form.children %}
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        {{ form_label(child) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The fact is, the label is going with the `form_widget` function. `form_label` returns empty string.

My form is I guess classic :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name1', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'Label 1',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'switchery'
            ],
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('name2', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'Label 2',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'switchery'
            ],
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('name3', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'Label 3',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'switchery'
            ],
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('name4', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'Label 4',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'switchery'
            ],
            'required' => false,
        ])
    ;
}
```

Did I missunderstand the doc ?

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap, this can be the expected behaviour, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26540

Comment: Yes it's absolutely answering this behaviour, thanks a lot, will change it so